# Scrollbar doesn't appear in droplist in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const select = document.querySelectorAll('.selectBtn');
const option = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
let index = 1;

select.forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', b => {
    const next = b.target.nextElementSibling;
    next.classList.toggle('toggle');
    next.style.zIndex = index++;
  })
})
option.forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', b => {
    b.target.parentElement.classList.remove('toggle');
    
    const parent = b.target.closest('.select').children[0];
    parent.setAttribute('data-type', b.target.getAttribute('data-type'));
    parent.innerText = b.target.innerText;
  })
})
```

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.select .selectBtn {
  background: var(--bg1);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
}
.select .selectBtn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 15px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-right: 2px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.select .selectBtn.toggle {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.select .selectBtn.toggle:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
          transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}
.select .selectDropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: var(--bg1);
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
          transform: scale(1, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
          transform-origin: top center;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.select .selectDropdown .option {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select .selectDropdown .option:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.select .selectDropdown.toggle {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
          transform: scale(1, 1);
}



body {
  margin: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
 <div class="select">
        <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">First option</div>
        <div class="selectDropdown">
            <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">1</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="secondOption">2</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="thirdOption">3</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="forthOption">4</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="fifthOption">5</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="sixthOption">6</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="sixthOption">7</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="sixthOption">8</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="sixthOption">9</div>
            <div class="option" data-type="sixthOption">10</div>
        </div>
```

I added the scrollbar in ".select .selectDropdown" and doesn't appear and cannot use it. I only want to show 5 items in default and the rest have to go down with scrollbar. I have tried several ways and cannot make it. I really appreciate if anyone can tell me the way to do it. Thanks

---

I have no idea what to add more details and website ask me to add more

Comment: PLeasy show us some code we cannot debug from nothing

Comment: sorry I accidentally deleted the code before i submit. Now i added@callmenikk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.select .selectDropdown {max-height:100px}
```

you need to give a height to that dropdown to get scroll, you can change 100px as you need